# Performing ajax Checks Before Form Sumbit via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, asynchronous

I have a simple form which is used to sign up a new user . I want to prevent users from submitting the same email id again . So before the form gets submitted , I want to do an Ajax check if the email id exists or not . If the email id exists , I alert the user . If it doesnt , I let the form be submitted .

```
$("#sign_in_form").submit(function(event){ 

event.preventDefault();
$.post("http://xyz.com/check_if_user_exists", {
        email : $("#contact_person_email").val()
    }).done(function(data) {

var res = parseInt(data);
if(res==1){

//Email Exists
alert("Email exists . Please use different email " );
return false; //----------------------------1)

}else{
  //Email doesnt exist
return true;   //--------------------------- 2)
}

});

//end of function

});
```

The problem with this code is due to async nature of Javascript , the function ends even before the result is returned from the ajax post statement . Hence the  return false or return true statement at 1) and 2) have no effect . Whats the correct way to handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submit form using js native event if check is valid:

```
$("#sign_in_form").submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("http://xyz.com/check_if_user_exists", {
        email: $("#contact_person_email").val()
    }).done(function (data) {

        var res = parseInt(data);
        if (res == 1) {

            //Email Exists
            alert("Email exists . Please use different email ");

        } else {
            document.getElementById('sign_in_form').submit();
        }

    });

    //end of function

});
```

Comment: But wont this lead to the $("#sign_in_form").submit() function being called again , hence a recursion happening ?

Comment: no, because using submit() on node element (js) won't trigger jquery submit handler

Comment: +1  but What's the problem in OP's code ? What if he just want to invoke alert instead of submitting automatically.

Comment: OP's code won't submit form because ajax is async and so submit here return nothing or if OP remove the preventing default behaviour, the form will always be submited even his check logic return false

Comment: Opening Poster, here the OP is you ;)